# How to use table instead of gridview?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, gridview

I dont know if the my question is good or bad or duplicate but I really want to ask you a favor. 
My designer gave me grid design using html tables which looks quite handsome but when I use the same css classes in asp gridview it totally looks different.

Additional Info: In my project I have used Telerik grids. I have tried applying all the css at that too but of no use. 
I cant change the designer css because its for all our company.

**Now at last I want to use the same table as designer gave me and use it as grid but i really dont know how to fill it from datatable?**
[image: here is what my design is.]

Comment: please use listview. the generated markup will be super flexible then

Answer (score 1):

```
1. GridView generates/renders code in which it is difficult to impossible to modify.
2. I would stay away from Telerik as well.
3. Use Bootstrap CSS, you should be very happy with bootstrap css framework as you will get that look above very easily.
```

With Bootstrap you would use classes like  class=table table-striped and you effectively have a nice grid with alternating row colors just like I see in the image that you posted.

With ASP.NET , use Nuget and install Bootstrap.  Reference in Masterpage or layout.

I assume that you have styles that overwrite what your designer gave to you.  Perhaps also if you are using THEIR stylesheets, make sure to overwrite the default styles.  Either OMIT the style reference in master page etc... or place their stylesheet references below the default in say a asp.net web forms or mvc application.  ( I assume web forms with masterpage since you are saying Gridview).

Comment: I am using bootstrap but its a bit customised according to our needs like colors.

Comment: You might want to play with the code in jsfiddle, or even save a fiddle and post it.

Comment: yes sure. https://jsfiddle.net/affablezaki/td6L57aL/
Now how to convert that into asp gridview ?

Comment: I'm saying to not use Gridview.  If you want to use gridview, view the source and start adding in classes into tags and perhaps some post rendering to the asp.net engine with  jquery DOM ready once loaded  , but look at the basic classes               <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView to include  components. here is the example code for ListView.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" GroupPlaceholderID="group" GroupItemCount="1" ItemPlaceholderID="item" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="group"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="item"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  border="1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span>
                                <%# Eval("Id") %>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Name: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB") %></span><br />
                            Number: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB") %></span><br />
                            Date: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB", "{0:MM dd, yyyy}") %></span><br />
                            Comment: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB") %></span><br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```